# Iam getting a TLE for a code to print sum of all primes between given 2 numbers(inclusive) in java

Tags: java

`

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  class TestClass {
  public static long prime(long l,long r){
    boolean flag=false;
    long count=0;
    long i,j;
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++){
        flag=false;
        if(i>=2){
            for(j=2;j<i;j++){
               if(i%j==0){
                   flag=true;
                   break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==false){
                count+=i;
            }
        }
        
    }
    return count;
}
public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int i=0;
    int x=t;
    long res[]=new long[t];
    while(t>0){
        StringTokenizer s=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        long l=Long.parseLong(s.nextToken());
        long r=Long.parseLong(s.nextToken());
        res[i]=prime(l,r);
        t--;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        System.out.println(res[i]);
    }
```

`

I don't know what is the reason for TLE for my code. How can I optimize my code inorder to get rid of that error? Can anyone help me to find the optimal solution for my code.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your code, eliminate unnecessary variables. For prime numbers, just repeat up to sqrt (n):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class TestClass {

public static long sumPrime(long l, long r) {
    long count = 0;
    for (long n = l; n <= r; n++) {
        if (isPrime(n)) count += n;
    }
    return count;
}

public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    for (long i = 2; i <= (long) Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Loop: ");
    int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    long[] res = new long[t];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        System.out.print("(l-r)?: ");
        String[] s = br.readLine().split(" ");
        long l = Long.parseLong(s[0]);
        long r = Long.parseLong(s[1]);
        res[i] = sumPrime(l, r);
    }
    System.out.print("Result: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d  ", res[i]);
        }
    }
}
```